# How to use completely custom component in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**Current Situation**

I have an app that provides custom views. The html files, css, javascript and images are zipped in zip file then converted and stored in database as blob column.

These files are kept cached on Jboss server side to be requested and used on page request that contains any custom view.

**What's wanted**

There are multiple approaches I've read to load dynamic components using `Compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync` and also by injecting `ComponentFactoryResolver` and use it to create components dynamically.

But I would like to inject custom views/components using Angular since this project is under revamp demand to be SPA using Angular. The custom view will contain **TypeScript** code provides some custom business logic, **html** which typically should be the template & custom **css**.

- Is this possible ? I guess using AngularJS it would be since injected JavaScript in run-time wouldn't be a problem
- If yes, how ?
- Any libraries/frameworks available already provides custom views creating and saving/retrieving their data ?